# failed to load: coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServlet?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Tried CF10 Restful API and this is what I get:

```
INFO: failed to load: coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServlet
May 28, 2014 11:23:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet CFRestServlet
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at coldfusion.util.CaseInsensitiveMap.put(CaseInsensitiveMap.java:71)
    at coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServlet.initContainerPairs(CFRestServlet.java:115)
    at coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServlet.init(CFRestServlet.java:106)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:121)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Anyone encountered this?

I tried all possible paths.... even include the cfusion or instance name, CF just doesn't work.

Cross post: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1484514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by re-installing CF10.

There was a dangling rest endpoint that could not be deleted before I reinstall.  I guess that was related.